# Object oriented javascript for event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Hi i tried to modularize my javascript and make it object oriented, but i got confused when i tried to do it with component with multiple instances.

My code looks like this

HTML file

```
   <div id="1" class="home-post-list" data-id="1">
         <div class="home-post-list-hide">
         </div>
   </div>
   <div id="2" class="home-post-list" data-id="2">
        <div class="home-post-list-hide">
         </div>

   </div>
```

The HTML ids above (#1, #2) are randomly generated from the server.

This is the code currently (NOT OOP),

```
$(document).on('click', '.home-post-list', function(e){ 
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   var $widget = $("#" + id);
   $widget.find('.home-post-list-hide').hide();
});

$(document).on('mouseover', '.home-post-list', function(e) {
      var id = $(this).data('id');
   var $widget = $("#" + id);
   $widget.find('.home-post-list-hide').show();
});
```

I want to make something like this.

```
var HomePostList = function(){
    this.$widget = this.find('.home-post-list-hide');
    this.init();
};

HomePostList.prototype.init() {
    //event handling
}
```

the reason i want to make it OOP, because i want to make communication between components and i don't have to rewrite $widget.find('.home-post-list-hide').hide() many times.

Comment: I'm not following. OOP is just a way of structuring your code. Nothing you show there implies OOP and by using OOP, that does not require you to do server-side rendering.

Comment: You can connect with server side using AJAX.

Comment: i want to structure my javascript to become object oriented, currently i just do one event in one function

Comment: @NiharSarkar i didn't say any ajax in my question, i just wanted to know how to structure my javascript code into object oriented.

Comment: 'I heard somewhere that my code should be blue. How can I make my code more blue?'. OOP is just a phrase, it means many different things depending on context. Nor is it some sort of magic formula for coding success. There isn't anything really wrong with the code you posted. POST EDIT: you are looking to take clear, readable jquery and turn it into that mess? On purpose?

Comment: @JaredSmith i want to make it OOP because i have to find '.home-post-list-hide' everytime it is fired

Comment: @RobertLimanto and that goal has...what to do with OOP? This question is the classic xy problem (google it). Your real goal is to keep a reference to an event handler, that is completely orthogonal to OOP.

Comment: i also want to make communications between component, for example like show a modal, i can just do it with $modal.show();, but i have a problem with multiple modals, because i will not know which modal to be triggered

Comment: Then *change your question to be about that*. Remove all mentions of OOP. If OOP is the correct solution, it will show in the answer. If not, then not. But 'how do I do x using y?' is a classic SO question anti-pattern. Just ask 'how do I do x?', preferably with examples of the desired behavior and what you've already tried. The fact that *all* of the feedback you've gotten (despite multiple attempts to clarify) has been confused or negative should be your clue that you are barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
var HomePostList = function($root){
    this.$root = $root;
    this.$widget = this.$root.find('.home-post-list-hide');
    this.init();
};

HomePostList.prototype.init() {
    //event handling
}


list = []
$(".home-post-list").each(function(el){
    list.push(HomePostList($(el)));
});
```

Comment: hmm, okay, but i don't know the ids of the Homepostlist, it depends on what the server side generated

Comment: @RobertLimanto I edited example code to find elements by class.

Comment: I think so, but it's been a while since I wrote something in JS ;)

Comment: thanks, i have another question, please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961648/call-parent-component-method-from-child-component-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It looks (from the comments) that what you are *really* trying to do here is cache your DOM access so that you don't have to find the elements over and over again. You could accomplish that with a pattern like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.home-post-list', (function(e) {
   var element = null // we'll lazily set this on the first event
   return function(e) {
     // by using the conditional here, find only gets executed once:
     // the first time the event fires.
     if (!element) {
        // note that instead of 'this' I'm using the event target.
        // the 'this' context is lost in handlers, that's why OOP
        // is arguably a sub-optimal fit here
        element = $("#" + $(e.currentTarget).data('id')).find('.home-post-list-hide');
     }
     element.hide();
   };
});
```

As I said above, OOP is not something like Boolean false where you can say 'false' and everyone knows what you're talking about. Nor does adding the buzzword 'modularize' help much. Ask about problems in a way that avoids presupposing you know what the solution should be.