# Call Parent Component Method from Child Component in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i call Parent Component method from child component.

For example, parent component (Called P) has modal and a subcomponent (Called S).
S has text area and button, when button is clicked, modal in parent has to be called.

My solution is (Please give comment whether this is bad practice or not, How if the Parent Component is different across the exact same subcomponents)

Parent Component:

```
var P = function(root) {
     this.root = root; 
     this.S = new S(this.root.find('.s'), this);
     this.modal = this.root.find('modal');
}
P.prototype.closeModal_ = function(e) {//code};
```

SubComponent

```
var S = function(root, parent) {
      this.root = root;
      this.parent = parent;
      this.button = this.root.find('button');
}
S.prototype.sendButton_ = function(e) {
      this.parent.closeModal();
}
```

Comment: If your only question is about good or bad practice you should consider asking your question on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: ok , i will repost it, but i could not do it now, 40 minutes one time

Comment: can you answer first?